# Django App for Production Server using nginx and Gunicorn

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, nginx, server

I am trying to build a Django dashboard app for a production server using Nginx and Gunicorn. The app is running on the Nginx server. The login and authentication page is also working fine. I am using the default SQLite. The dashboard will retrieve sensor data and display on the dashboard in the form of charts on the dashboard. The user can reboot and power off the server from the Dashboard. There will be additional features too.

Problem:

I am trying to build the reboot and power off functionality using javascript (I am a newbie and learning through multiple coding attempts) but I am unable to find a script. most of the suggestions on the internet is directing towards node.js.

So please suggest me if there is a way in making these functionalities through javascript or shall I start learning node.js.

If someone has already built a similar project and its available on Internet kindly share the link.

Comment: what is your objection to using node js?

Comment: I have created 2 push button for "Reboot" and "Power Off" from the Dashboard using HTML and CSS. the javascript for confirm is working fine. so I want to add a functionality that when user click on "OK" the server should reboot or power off depending on the push button. but i am not able to perform this function through javascript and I am looking for suggestions and it is advicing me for node.js